# passing data to controller from view in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm new to cakephp. I went through Andrew Perkins's video tutorials. It is a great tutorial for absolute beginners.
What I want to do is get the username to a hidden field from login page and keep it in a view.and pass it to the controller and save it to the database when it is necessary.

right now I have a add.ctp, BabiesController.php as the controller and baby.php as the model.
since I haven't completed the login page I would like to hard code the username for instance.

here are my codes. hope you guys can help me.
this is the database.emails address has been used as primary key for babyprents table.parent column int the babies table is a foreign key to the email address in the babyparents table.
[image]

Model : **baby.php**

```
<?php

class Baby extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Baby';

}
```

Controller : **BabiesController.php**

```
<?php

class BabiesController extends  AppController {
var $name = 'Baby';

function index()
{
    $this->set('babies',$this->Baby->find('all'));
}

function  add()
{
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash($this->data);
        if($this->Baby->save($this->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Successful');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('unsuccessful');
        }

    }
}
}
```

View: **add.ctp**

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<?php
echo $this->form->create('Baby',array('action'=>'add'));


echo $this->form->input('firstName');
echo $this->form->input('middleName');
echo $this->form->input('lastName');
echo $this->form->input('birthday');
echo $this->form->input('age');
echo $this->form->input('doctor');
echo $this->form->end('Sign up');
?>
```

all the data has been saved except for email address.any guide will be appreciated. thank you all.

Comment: Please add the version of cakephp you're using.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I'm using cakephp-2.4.9

Comment: Your form is incomplete? I do not see email field.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all: do you have a user logged in? Is this user the parent of the baby or the user is a superuser than can add babies to whoever parent. In the firs case you should already have the email stored somewhere (i.e. session), in the second case you can build a select input with all the emails fo the parents

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use **saveAll($this->data)**:

```
function  add()
{
if(!empty($this->data))
{
    $this->Session->setFlash($this->data);
    if($this->Baby->saveAll($this->data))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Successful');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('unsuccessful');
    }

  }
}
```

In your add.ctp put this line

```
echo $this->form->input('Babyparent.email');
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm sorry but I need to save it in a session or some kind of variable and pass it to controller to save it.I don't want to prompt it to user to enter email address.thank you again.

Comment: I get the email address from the login page.since I haven't implemented login page. for the demonstration I would like to hard coded answer. so I can apply it.

Comment: I assume that you have a 'users' table, where they are stored login information, including email login? In this case, make the relation between users and babyparents models. Later, when you want to display data also show those from relational tables, eg users.email.